Get parent parser from argparse's parser
I have certain python code which takes CLI arguments and handles them using argparse's parser. I have a parent parser as such:
verbose_quiet_parent_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)

And I have a parser which takes the verbose_quiet_parent_parser as a parent:
child_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog=command_name, description=command_description,
                                   formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter,
                                   epilog=EPILOG,
                                   parents=[verbose_quiet_parent_parser])

I want to write tests for my child_parser which'll make sure that verbose_quiet_parent_parser is a parent to my child_parser parser. I know I can do that by writing tests which provide the arguments that are recognisable by the verbose_quiet_parent_parser and the test would pass if there is no exception, but that will soon become repeatative as I'll have more child-parsers which'll have the verbose_quiet_parent_parser as a parent.
So, I want to somehow get the list of parents from child_parser for parent-parser verification.
The thing is, I am not able to find a way to get all the parents from my child-parser. A simple way to get parents from a child-parser would be something like:
child_parser.parents

But there is no such method/attribute in the ArgumentParser class. How can I get the parents from a parser or a better way to write tests which won't require checking for parent parser?

The arguments of the parent are copied by reference to the new parser. Other than that the parent is not retained as an attribute.  Nothing in the child tells you what parents were used during its creation.

In argparse.py look for parent and _add_container_actions method to see what happens when you specify a parents list. parents is a conveience feature. It isn't fundamental to the definition or operation of a parser.

@hpauljis it a good idea to use internals such as _add_container_actions?
Also, it just sets defaults and does not maintain parents list.

I'm not suggesting you use or change it.  I mention it just so you can see where and how parents are used.

Such a test would be tied to tightly to the implementation of the child parser. You care that child_parser correctly parses a given option, not how that option is defined for the child parser.

First of, as jpaulj mentioned, the ArgumentParser object does not keep a list of "parents" parsers. Secondly, I believe the ultimate goal here is to ensure that:

The child parser is created without any conflicts with its parents
The child parser include the functionalities that the parents provide

Testing #1 is easy: If you has a conflict, you will get an exception.
Testing the #2, which you have done. The problem is you don't want to have the same test for every child parsers. In my opinion, you only need the parents functionalities for one child. You don't have to do it for every child.
